# App data is not restored when device is restored via iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, backup, app-store-connect, icloud, restore

Users have reported that, when they restore a device from an iCloud (as opposed to an iTunes) backup, the data for my app is not restored. It is not clear to me the steps I need to take to ensure that my app data is restored when the entire device is restored from an iCloud backup.

I do not have iCloud enabled in app capabilities; is this one of the steps I need to take to make sure my data is included in the restore? What are the other steps I need to take and things I need to check?

More info:
I have a Core Data app and store a .sqlite file. I store my file in [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] applicationDocumentsDirectory]. I use NSUserDefaults. My app doesn't appear in any list for iCloud within Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to include iCloud capabilities. iCloud backs up automatically what is saved into `DocumentsDirectory` and also saves `NSUserDefaults`.

Bear in mind that for those datas you **don't want** to be included in iCloud, you must add `- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *) filePathString` flag. Apple is very strict with this backup and you must save only **user-generated content**, or else app will be rejected.

> Important: Apps should avoid mingling app data and user data in the
>   same file. Doing so will unnecessarily increase backup sizes and can
>   be considered a violation of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

To check how much space your app use in iCloud Backup (and figure out if your data is saved or not) you can check here:

```
- Install and launch your app
- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage
- Select your device
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
- Check your app's storage
```

If you know your app should store bigger data you will see there but please note that what is under 100-150kb is from `NSUserDefaults`

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying in the first part of your answer. My app does not appear in my list for my iCloud Backup (I really don't use iCloud backup, though there are a few apps in the list you described above, not including mine).

Comment: @SAHM You don't use neither one NSUserDefault in your app? Try to put only one and see if your app appears. Can you tell me what your app does?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I have a Core Data app. I store my file in [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] applicationDocumentsDirectory]. I use NSUserDefaults. My app doesn't appear in any list for iCloud.

Comment: Okay. My device wasn't appearing under Manage Storage because I hadn't done any backups. Once I increased my iCloud Storage and did a backup, I selected my device, showed all apps, and found my app. I guess the users that were reporting issues had unchecked the app, or had another problem with their backup/restores. Thank you!